# Remove <br /> after image using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

I have...

```
<td align="right" vAlign="top">
<img src="test/test.gif" width="1" height="4" border="0"><br />
Number<font color="#CC0000">*</font>:
</td><td></td><td>
```

How do I ditch that hanging `<br />` with jquery? I've tried a ton of examples here ,but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Ugh, where did you get that HTMLy mess? `<font>` tags are so 2000.

Comment: I totally and utterly agree! Not my code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove all `<br>` that follow an `<img>` you can use this:

```
$('img + br').remove()
```

If you prefer it to apply only to those inside a `<td>`:

```
$('td > img + br').remove()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! This one narrowed it down for me:
$('td > img + br').remove()

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this?

```
$("img").next("br").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('img + br').remove();
```

This seems to be, in Chromium 22/Ubuntu 12.10, just under twice as fast as the approach using `next()`: [JS Perf comparison](http://jsperf.com/test-of-next-method-versus-adjacent-sibling).

References:

- [CSS adjacent-sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

Answer (score 0):

really no reason to use JavaScript here, because it can be easily done with CSS:

```
img + br {display:none;}
```

;-)